# Finishing time of cyclic graphs in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a question about the strongly connected graphs(graph with cycle) so basically I would like to know what is the finishing time of this graph.
and how can I decide whether graph is strongly connected or not based on its finishing time?
I have seen some people mentioning reversing the direction of arcs and stuff like that but couldn't understand the concept behind it.

Comment: What don't you understand about "reversing the direction of arcs"?

Comment: "The finishing time f[v] is the number of nodes discovered or finished before finishing
the expansion of v " from  https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/handouts/quiz2review.pdf.  But what is the finishing time of a graph?

Answer (score 0):

Check Out Kosaraju Sharir or Tarjan for strongly connected component detection. Complexitys are asintotically the same O(n+m) even though Kosaraju is sligthly slower due to double DFS.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the finishing time of this graph

Finishing time is for a node and not for a graph. It's measured as the time taken to visit the node when you traverse the graph using a traversing algorithm.

> I have seen some people mentioning reversing the direction of arcs and
> stuff like that but couldn't understand the concept behind it.

I've explained it in Quora: https://qr.ae/pr8mWJ